# Angular Material md-data-table collapsible rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there a way to make a row expandable to show more info. With some type of directive or maybe a library that can be used with the angular material data table?

Comment: [**`ngIf`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), [**`ngShow`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Thanks is that the best wasy to do that though?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Since it's an ng-repeat it expands all the rows at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I guess you are using `ng-repeat` with something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in items">
    <td>{{i.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="i in items" ng-click="selected = $index">
  <td>{{i.firstname}}</td>
  <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="selected == $index">
  <td colspan="2">More infos!</td>
</tr>
```

### [Here is a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/5/)